# How to select multiple items from JList and save those to MySQL database in single column in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jlist

I am using JList but right now I can select only single item from JList. How can I select multiple items from the Jlist and save them to MySQL table in a single column.

code I used to display the selected values  :

```
    String s = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();
System.out.println("Value Selected: " + s);
```

but it only shows single item from JList

Comment: By pressing Ctrl key, you can select multiple

Comment: @Sambit Yes but whwn disply the values it shows only one value.  code i used   :                                                                                                                'String s = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();
System.out.println("Value Selected: " + s);'

Comment: Can you post the code so that I can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to use

```
setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION)
```

on **JList**
and then you can use
`getSelectedValuesList()` or `getSelectedIndices()`

Comment: aftre list selection mode this line helped  'List<String> strList = jList1.getSelectedValuesList();'

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below the java docs for JList.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValuesList()

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

You can get all the selected JList values using **getSelectedValuesList()** which provides a List type.

I assume in you case, it should be

```
List<String> strList = jList1.getSelectedValuesList();
```

Comment: I can now select multiple values from JList but how to save them in MySQL table  in a single column.

Comment: You can write query to save the selected values into database. Before that you have to learn jdbc connection.

Comment: I know JDBC connection. Done it.